# Get date and time from date picker and time picker

Tags: java, android

I have a date picker and 4 time pickers in my application. I want to display a notification at given date at all the 4 times given by the user. How do I do it?

I store the all the values separately as integer in my database like year, month, dayofmonth, hour of time 1, minute of time 1.... But there must be some other way to  do that display notification right?

Also I have a field asking how many days I want to display notification. So that notification will be displayed for every time I have given to the end of number of days
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the comment below ( storing date and time)

What you do is...

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

Calendar now = Calendar,getInstance();

long i = now.getTimeInMillis();

editor.putLong("date", i);

editor.commit();
```

To get the value again...

```
Calendar stored = Calendar.getInstance();

long a = sp.getLong("date", 0);

stored.set(0,0,0,0,0);

stored.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, a);
```

Comment: I am not using share preferences... But the answer gave me the idea how to get correct date. Thankyou

Comment: Sweet as. What are you storing it in?

Comment: I'm taking the values directly from the database using adapter class. Also about the time difference came because of the locale I used was different from my time zone. that was why it happened

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit harder then it may seem.

What you want to do is create an alarm at the 4 given times and have a broadcast receiver that displays the notifications.

just comment if you need to know how to do this

Comment: I need to know because I'm just an amateur in android...
Now I've started to store the date and time as long value in my database but when the value is returned and doing all those calculations like longvalue/(1000*60) gives me a time difference of 6 hours. Sorry for replying to your post this lately

Comment: sorry it's 5 and a half hours

Comment: IF you want to store a date as a long value, using a calendar. Ill post it in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager to get notifications of events.